# App built on React (frontend) and Node Express on the same port (Stripe integration)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I have an existing online shop app created with React on the front end and I am trying to integrate STRIPE as payment method using NODE express on backend. I would like to start them on the same port and I tried with the proxy in package.json and by serving index.html as static file but it doesnt work.

I do serve index.html as static file but it doesnt seems to read anything else except the html.
Here is my code:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config('.env');
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const path = require('path')
import Products from './src/components/Products';
import CartItem from './src/components/context/cartProvider';


const app = express();

// I am trying to serve the whole React app as static file
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
  })




// ENDPOINTS FOR SESSION HERE

app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {



    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items: [
        // Here we have to send clonedCart[] as body
      ],
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: "https://example.com/success",
      cancel_url: "https://example.com/cancel",
    });
  
    res.json({ id: session.id });
  });  



app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server is running on port 4000'))
```

In package.json I have added the following line:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
```

Worth naming that React is execute on the default port :3000

Comment: You like wouldn't need a proxy here. From your comments, my guess is that your React bundle isn't being referenced in the index.html file that you're hosting. A single page React app basically boils down to an index.html file that includes a JavaScript bundle of your app, which is usually prepared using Webpack. I'd recommend taking a look at you index.html file and ensuring that it includes your app bundle. The way you are serving up the static file also seems a bit off. Normally you would just need a line like: `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serving static html from node.js server code, will not work. As you are using just the public folder html, it can't be used. To use it you need to use the build version.

What I can understand from your question is that,you need to run them on the same port,because you might be getting cors error. So use the cors module.